# Spring MVC Controller to Parse A JSON FILE TO HASHMAP FOR REDIS DB

Tags: java, json, spring, curl

I have to build a Spring MVC project with java to handle an http post request of a json file and parse it to a hashmap. 
I just need to know how to handle an http post request sent through CURL and parse/read the data coming from that json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here are the steps on how to achieve this

1. Create a sample Spring MVC app (there are many tutorials on the web)
2. Use a file upload library i.e. Apache Commons File Upload
3. You can configure the file upload property in spring's application context to state how much the size of the file should be
4. Use Spring web's **Multipart File** in a request mapping to map your post request
5. Read the recently uploaded **Multipart File** and convert it into **HashMap** depending on structure of the file
6. Insert the **Hashmap** into Redis

Here are some useful SO question about the same topic

- [Spring MVC File Upload Help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577942/spring-mvc-file-upload-help)
- [Spring : File Upload RESTFUL Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884711/spring-file-upload-restful-web-service)

And some external links

- http://consistentcoder.com/spring-4-mvc-file-upload-example
- http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-single-multiple-files
- http://www.concretepage.com/spring-4/spring-4-mvc-single-multiple-file-upload-example-with-tomcat

Comment: Brief explanation. Nice